# Bits' transmission in links

Tags: current

> It is sometimes useful to think of bandwidth in terms of how long it takes to transmit each bit of data.

Say we have a series of bits 100101101 to transmit and they are represented as +5V(1) 0V(0).

What is the transmission of each single bit in terms of electrons flowing in the cable ? 
What does +5V mean for electrons that represent the bits ? (faster electrons or longer duration of flow of electrons)

Do we wait for a bit to reach the other side before sending the next ?

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't have to wait until the bit has arrived before sending the next one. A signal will travel at about 2/3 of light speed in vacuum in a wire, that's 200 000 km/s, or 20 m in 100 ns. A bit every 100 ns is 10 Mbps, and there are many systems which go faster than that. At 100 Mbps the first bit will be 2 m down the cable before the next one starts.

The

> how long it takes to transmit each bit of data

refers to the transmitter only, and ignores the travel time through the cable. At 1 Mbps you start sending the first bit at time zero, and the next bit will start at time zero plus 1 µs, no matter how far the previous bit is in the cable. A system with ten times that throughput will start the second bit at time zero plus 0.1 µs. I'm saying "throughput" and not "bandwidth" because they're not exactly the same. The 1 Mbps signal may use the same bandwidth as the 10 Mbps signal, if the latter is allowed to have some edge distortion for instance. A higher bandwidth will give a more accurate representation of the original waveform, though the medium (the cable) may also deteriorate that.

A higher voltage allows the signal to go further in terms of the resistance it meets, but it won't travel faster. Note that you don't need electrons to send a signal: in optical fiber it's photons that do the job.

Comment: Thanks, does it mean that more than one representation of a bit can travel through the cable at the same time ? something like the waves in the sea ?

Comment: @Eggplants - Yes, for the example of the 100 Mbps (I seem to have lost a "0", fixed), in a 20 m long cable there will always be 10 bits at a time traveling through it. Bit 0 won't be received until bit 10 has been transmitted.